# Keyword argument 'ssh -o ProxyCommand' is not supported by this keyword. Robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am trying to run the process:

```
Run Process       python   ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p 10.10.10.10' 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

But am getting below error:

"Keyword argument 'ssh -o ProxyCommand' is not supported by this keyword"

Need help here to run my command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the documentation for [Run Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process):

> Note that possible equal signs in *arguments must be escaped with a backslash (e.g. name\=value) to avoid them to be passed in as **configuration.

So, you need to put a `\` before the `=`:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand\=...
```

You probably also need to remove `python` , and you also probably need to use `shell=True`, but that's not related to the question you asked about this specific error message.

Comment: Thank you, Bryan. It worked. How will I come to know this command got executed?
My test case says = PASS. But still, how can I see it on report?